# Почему оператор delete не удаляет локальную переменную внутри функции?

Tags: javascript

```
var output = (function(x){
    delete x;
    return x;
})(0);

console.log(output);
```

Вопрос в следующем - почему `x` не удаляется, ведь оно является свойством `arguments`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `delete` может удалять только свойства объекта:

> `delete` эффективен только применительно к свойствам объектов. Он не оказывает никакого влияния на имена переменных и функций.

[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description).

А поскольку `x` является записью Declarative Environment Record (очень грубо говоря - не является свойством объекта, а просто переменной), то и удалить переменную таким образом нельзя.

Более того, даже не всякое свойство объекта можно удалить при помощи оператора `delete` (и я сейчас не о дескрипторах свойств, хотя это и самое очевидное). Например, нельзя удалить свойство глобального объекта, определенное не явно, а как переменная. Например:

```js
var a = 1;
console.log(a === this.a); // `a` является свойством глобального объекта

delete a; //false
console.log(a); // 1
```

Однако:

```js
this.a = 1;
console.log(a === this.a); // все еще равны

delete a; // true
console.log(a); // error
```

---

### Из комментариев

> А разве x не является свойством псевдо-массива arguments?

Разумеется, является.

```js
"use strict";

(function(x){
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    delete arguments[0];
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    console.log(x); // все еще есть!
}(0));
```

Но поскольку удалить можно только свойство **объекта**, то и обращаться нужно непосредственно к свойству **объекта**. Однако при помощи такого подхода вы и удалите только свойство объекта. А, поскольку локальные переменные (точнее говоря, формальные параметры функции) никак не связаны с объектом `arguments`, то формальный параметр `x` по-прежнему доступен (именно как локальная переменная, но не как свойство `arguments`).

Comment: А разве x не является свойством псевдо-массива arguments?

Comment: @ПавелЮхневич отличное замечание, сейчас дополню.